# get json object with # in object name using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, api, object, last.fm

- i'm using the recentracks api from lastFm:

www.last.fm/api/show?service=278

- i used these sources to see how to use it:

api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29

- i'm fetching the json format:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=melroymusic&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?

i want to retrieve the name of the artist

```
{"track":[{"artist":{"#text":"deadmau5","mbid":""}
```

Logically i would use

```
item.artist.#text
```

total code:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=melroymusic&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?",

function(data){
    $.each(data.recenttracks.track, function(i,item){
    $("#lastfmMenu").append("<div class='lastfmItem'><div class='lastfmText'>"+item.artist.#text+"</div>" + "<div class='lastfmDate'>"+item.name+"</div></div>");
    });
});
```

doesnt work

i haven't found a code that could retrieve an object with #

i also saw @attr object i also wanted to use

```
 "@attr":{"nowplaying":"true"}
```

i dont know how to solve it and couldnt find anything about it

look at http://mellroy.com/ to see how it's working out

Thank you in advance, really appreciated

Comment: have you tried item.artist["#text"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's use of jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var json = {"track":[{"artist":{"#text":"deadmau5","mbid":""}]};

$.each(json.track, function (b, c) {
    console.log('Index' + b, c.artist['#text']); // index 0 deadmau5
});
```

Comment: thank you, that was easy, the same goes for @attr i guess? :['@attr']